# Не отслеживается изменение input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, onchange

Имеется следующий код:

```
<input id="calc" type="text" value="1">
$("#calc").on("change input", function () {
    var val_input = parseInt($(this).val());
    alert(val_input);
});
```

При вводе с клавиатуры выводится alert как положено. 
Если управлять значением этого инпута кнопкой с событием on("click") то значение  меняется но alert не срабатывает. В чем проблема?

Comment: Может несколько элементов с id calc на странице?

Answer (score 2):

Все работает.

```js
 
$("#calc").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
  var val_input = parseInt($(this).val());
    alert(val_input);          
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="calc" type="number" value="1">
```

Comment: Это клик по тому же инпуту, я же писал  "Если управлять значением этого инпута кнопкой" т.е. есть отдельно кнопка на странице при клике на которую значение в поле меняется, а алерт не срабатывает!

Comment: при клике на карту значение в input меняется, результат не считается

Comment: Я ведь выше скинул ссылку, по ней только одна карта.

Comment: Даниил огромное спасибо, так сложно оказалось объяснять проблему, что мне кажется проще будет, если я сам разберусь)) Вы лучший мастер, что я встречал!

Comment: @АлександрKrassnow не за что, всегда рад помочь. Учитесь задавать правильные вопросы. Читайте документацию к карте.[YandexMap](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/MapEvent-docpage/)